# Issue Merging Two Layers in an LSTM Seq2Seq Model for Q&A Use Case

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to build a Q&A model based off of the [bAbI Task 8 example](https://research.fb.com/downloads/babi/) and I am having trouble merging two of my input layers into one layer. Here is my current model architecture:

```
story_input = Input(shape=(story_maxlen,vocab_size), name='story_input')
story_input_proc = Embedding(vocab_size, latent_dim, name='story_input_embed', input_length=story_maxlen)(story_input)
story_input_proc = Reshape((latent_dim,story_maxlen), name='story_input_reshape')(story_input_proc)

query_input = Input(shape=(query_maxlen,vocab_size), name='query_input')
query_input_proc = Embedding(vocab_size, latent_dim, name='query_input_embed', input_length=query_maxlen)(query_input)
query_input_proc = Reshape((latent_dim,query_maxlen), name='query_input_reshape')(query_input_proc)

story_query = dot([story_input_proc, query_input_proc], axes=(1, 1), name='story_query_merge')

encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, name='encoder')
encoder_output, state_h, state_c = encoder(story_query)
encoder_output = RepeatVector(3, name='encoder_3dim')(encoder_output) 
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, name='decoder')(encoder_output, initial_state=encoder_states)
answer_output = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='answer_output')(decoder)

model = Model([story_input, query_input], answer_output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

and here is the output of model.summary()

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
story_input (InputLayer)        (None, 358, 38)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
query_input (InputLayer)        (None, 5, 38)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
story_input_embed (Embedding)   (None, 358, 64)      2432        story_input[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
query_input_embed (Embedding)   (None, 5, 64)        2432        query_input[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
story_input_reshape (Reshape)   (None, 64, 358)      0           story_input_embed[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
query_input_reshape (Reshape)   (None, 64, 5)        0           query_input_embed[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
story_query_merge (Dot)         (None, 358, 5)       0           story_input_reshape[0][0]        
                                                                 query_input_reshape[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder (LSTM)                  [(None, 64), (None,  17920       story_query_merge[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_3dim (RepeatVector)     (None, 3, 64)        0           encoder[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (LSTM)                  (None, 3, 64)        33024       encoder_3dim[0][0]               
                                                                 encoder[0][1]                    
                                                                 encoder[0][2]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
answer_output (Dense)           (None, 3, 38)        2470        decoder[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 58,278
Trainable params: 58,278
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

where vocab_size = 38, story_maxlen = 358, query_maxlen = 5, latent_dim = 64, and the batch size = 64.

When I try to train this model I get the error:

`Input to reshape is a tensor with  778240 values, but the requested shape has 20480`

Here is the formula for those two values:

`input_to_reshape = batch_size * latent_dim * query_maxlen * vocab_size`

`requested_shape = batch_size * latent_dim * query_maxlen`

## Where I'm At

I believe the error message is saying the shape of the tensor inputted into the `query_input_reshape` layer is (?, 5, 38, 64) but it is expecting a tensor of shape (?, 5, 64) (see formulas above), but I could be wrong on that.

When I change the target_shape input of Reshape to be 3D (i.e. `Reshape((latent_dim,query_maxlen,vocab_size)`) I get the error `total size of new array must be unchanged`, which doesn't make any sense to me because the input is 3D. You would think that `Reshape((latent_dim,query_maxlen))` would give me that error because it'd be changing a 3D tensor into a 2D tensor, but it compiles fine, so I've no clue what's going on there.

The only reason I'm using Reshape is because I need to merge the two tensors as an input into the LSTM encoder. When I try to get rid of the Reshape layers I just get dimension mismatch errors when I try to compile the model. The model architecture above at least compiles but I can't train it.

Can someone please help me figure out how I can merge the story_input and query_input layers? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you reshaping? That will mix the sentences together, perhaps you were trying to `Permute` instead(?)

Comment: @nuric yes, it should be Permute